# javascript variable from mysql database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

Hi I'm trying to plot multiple values and successfully done using this variable.

```
    var locations = [
  ['Bacolod City', 10.64073 ,122.9689, 4],
  ['Bago City', 10.5333 ,122.8333, 5],
  ['Cadiz City', 10.950, 123.29, 3],
  ['Sipalay City', 9.7519, 122.40, 2],
  ['Kabankalan City', 9.896, 122.831, 1]
];
```

Now my next step is instead of static data like above, I would like to retrieve data from my mysql database and use it for *var locations*. Would appreciate any help on how to perform that. most i have seen is complicated and use json which i have no experience in. Thanks in advance.

Note:Btw I'm trying to plot using google maps api. sorry for not mentioning.

Comment: `echo "var data = ".json_encode(data).";\n"`. That's not complicated.

Comment: @JanDvorak could you point me to a good tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read about Ajax or could use one of many tutorials:
http://www.php4every1.com/tutorials/jquery-ajax-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Articles](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/) section of the documentation there are several examples of how to use PHP/MySQL with the Google Maps API v3:

- [Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)
- [Creating a Store Locator with PHP & MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3)